# boot stuck after starting apache

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot, boot-issues

few months back I installed raspbian and configured apache etc..
I haven't used it for a few months and today I was trying to get it back running.
During the boot it hangs on
[OK] Started LSB: Apache2 web server

nothing happens

any idea for troubleshooting?

I would like to avoid reinstalling everything if possible :/

thanks!

Comment: Boot to another card and pop this in a reader and check the logs?

Comment: you know I feel stupid I haven't thought about about that at all!! Really first experience on raspberry! Perfect I will look into how to check the logs and post in here if have problems! Cheers!

Comment: mmmh checking in /var/log and all the files are not modified after jan (when it was still working..)